# SSIS Package says execution completed with success but there is no data in my table?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, ssms

I have this SSIS package that imports data from a tab file into my SQL Server.  When I debug or execute it shows that all the rows have gone through as in the following

[image]

But every time I go check the table in SQL Server it shows up like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: just checking as I have done this before.. are you looking at the right database for your select?

Comment: @Harry Yes sir.  I'm making sure its Master table in DBO Monthly.  Same goes in the destination in the SSIS package.

Comment: There could be a trigger on the table rejecting data. You could have a Truncate statement in this package or a different process is cleaning the table out. It could be that there's an Expression overwriting the connection string and data isn't going where you expect it to. More information needed.

Comment: Also, pedantic point - It's the master table in the dbo schema of the database Monthly

Comment: Related to what @Harry asked: are you sure you're looking on the right server? i.e.: the DestinationConnectionOLEDB connection manager in your BIDS screen shot could be pointing elsewhere.

Comment: Hi, Please add the Grid Data Viewer before destination and see if the data is being fetched or not, if you can see the data in the data viewer then there might be a trigger written on the table to truncate or delete the data as @billinkc suggested

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem a while back.  The problem is that you probably have your Error Output to ignore failure.  Put it back to Fail Component.  Now this is the tedious part.  Debug this and it WILL error.  But the error will tell you which column it is that is messing up and why.  From there, go back to your SQL server database table and see what the data type is for that column, go back to your ConnectionFlatFile source and change that column to what it is in SQL Server.  Rinse and repeat till you don't get any more errors and all the rows by the end of it should be in your database.

I don't know about a faster way but when i first set up a database i imported a bunch of flat files all as string[DT_STR] 255 just because it was the quickest.... but then i had to go back and fix each column datatype. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The logs can be viewed in the "Progress" tab. That must show 262927 records inserted to the destination table.

Comment: so i just checked in the progress, and i found this "[SSIS.Pipeline] Information: "Destination - MASTER" wrote 0 rows."  So i guess now the question is... why would it go through the process to write 0 rows..... The thing is this package was working a few days ago and it wasn't till recent that that particular table started showing up blank.